# AppBarButton: How to have 2 glyps as Icon

Tags: xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I have this;

```
               <AppBarToggleButton Label="" >
                    <AppBarToggleButton.Icon>
                        <FontIcon FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Glyph="&#xEC92;" />
                    </AppBarToggleButton.Icon>
                </AppBarToggleButton>
```

and it works fine, but I need to add another glyp overlapping that one.
`<FontIcon FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Glyph="&#xF0AE;" />`
I tried to add 2 Glips but I got an error.

```
               <AppBarToggleButton Label="" >
                    <AppBarToggleButton.Icon>
                        <FontIcon FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Glyph="&#xEC92;" />
                        <FontIcon FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Glyph="&#xF0AE;" />
                    </AppBarToggleButton.Icon>
                </AppBarToggleButton>
```

Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is:

```xml
<AppBarToggleButton Label="" >
    <AppBarToggleButton.Content>
        <Grid>
            <FontIcon FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Glyph="&#xEC92;" />
            <FontIcon FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Glyph="&#xF0AE;" />
        </Grid>
    </AppBarToggleButton.Content>
</AppBarToggleButton>
```

Comment: Sorry it does not work, I get these errors:
`Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error XDG0047 The specified value cannot be assigned. The following type was expected: "IconElement".` 
and 
`Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error XLS0504 Property 'Icon' does not support values of type 'Grid'.`

also I cannot compile: `1>XamlCompiler error WMC0015: Cannot assign 'Grid' into property 'Icon', type must be assignable to 'IconElement'`

Comment: Did you also change the `AppBarToggleButon.Icon` to `AppBarToggleButon.Content`?

Comment: me dummy! sorry I haven't noticed the change :) its Ok. Can I ask a second question? if I want the second glyph to be Half of the size (both height and width) of the first one? is there a way?

Comment: Of course. But it's bit OT. Please ask a different question.

Comment: Thank you, done. New question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61305902/how-to-have-glyps-overlapped-in-different-size